# How can i use the value of the id in my other table as i create it automated

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have these 2 tables `palle_tb` and `csvName` i am trying to use the `id` from `palle_tb` inside my `csvName` using `FK_Name` **the tables are connected** but i dont get any value inside the FK_Name.

I am pretty sure i should a variable inside `':FK_Name' =>` but dont know what to write since i already got this `FK_Name INT(11),
        FOREIGN KEY (FK_Name) REFERENCES palle_tb(id),`

This is my code:

```
public function createPalleTable($latest_filename){
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `palle_tb`(
        id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Palle_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Varenummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Ordre_nummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Operatoer VARCHAR(50), 
        Maskine_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Raavare_batch_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Dato_ur_stillet VARCHAR(50), 
        Klokke_fuldsvejst VARCHAR(50), 
        Fuldstoebning_af_klokke VARCHAR(50),
        Afgratning_af_overflade VARCHAR(50), 
        Vaegt DECIMAL(10,2))
      ");
}

public function insertPalleTable($latest_filename ,$palledata){
    return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `palle_tb` (`Palle_nr`, `Varenummer`, `Ordre_nummer`, `Operatoer`, `Maskine_nr`,
     `Raavare_batch_nr`, `Dato_ur_stillet`,`Klokke_fuldsvejst`,`Fuldstoebning_af_klokke`,`Afgratning_af_overflade`,`Vaegt`)
    VALUES (:Palle_nr, :Varenummer, :Ordre_nummer, :Operatoer, :Maskine_nr, :Raavare_batch_nr, :Dato_ur_stillet,
     :Klokke_fuldsvejst, :Fuldstoebning_af_klokke, :Afgratning_af_overflade, :Vaegt)",
        [
        ':Palle_nr' => $palledata[0],
        ':Varenummer'=> $palledata[1],
        ':Ordre_nummer'=> $palledata[2],
        ':Operatoer'=> $palledata[3],
        ':Maskine_nr'=> $palledata[4],
        ':Raavare_batch_nr'=> $palledata[5],
        ':Dato_ur_stillet'=> $palledata[6],
        ':Klokke_fuldsvejst'=> $palledata[7],
        ':Fuldstoebning_af_klokke'=> $palledata[8],
        ':Afgratning_af_overflade'=> $palledata[9],
        ':Vaegt'=> $palledata[10]
        ]
    );
}
/*The idea with the functions under this is that it creates a table with the Name of the data only and creates a foreign key to connect them*/
public function createCsvTable(){
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CsvName`(
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        FK_Name INT(11),
        FOREIGN KEY (FK_Name) REFERENCES palle_tb(id),
        Name VARCHAR(50))
      ");
}
public function insertCsvData($myArray){
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO CsvName (Name,FK_Name)
    VALUES (:Name,:FK_Name)",
        [
        ':Name' => $myArray[0], /*This array contains all my data, but when i add the [0] it only takes the Name*/
        ':FK_Name' => /*This should contain the id from the palle_tb i need help with how to get that*/
        ]
    );
}
```

If you need the button then here is the code for that. I need it to be automatic so a select with the foreign key wont do.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){

    copy("$sourcepath/$latest_filename","$copy/$latest_filename");
    // Here i split the csv file, from second line. and using the first and fourth lines as the headers.
    if (($openfile = fopen("$copy/$latest_filename", "r")) !== false) {

        $header1 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

        $csv->createPalleTable($latest_filename);
        $csv->insertPalleTable($latest_filename, array_map("toNumber", fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")));

        $delimiting_row = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use 
        $header2 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

        while($row = fgets($openfile)){  
            // can parse further $row by usingstr_getcsv

            $myArray = explode(';', $row);
            $myArray = array_map("utf8_encode", $myArray);
            $myArray = array_map("toNumber", $myArray);

            echo'<pre>';
            print_r($myArray);
            echo'</pre>';
            $csv->createCsvTable();
            $csv->insertCsvData($myArray);
        }
    }
    fclose($openfile);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe changing your function definition to this `public function insertCsvData($myArray, $id){`

Comment: and just make a variable like $id = ("SELECT id FROM palle_tb"); ?

Comment: Maybe not, if the array `$myArray` contains palle_tb, you could use it too, something like `':FK_Name' => $myArray[WHAT_palle_tb_INDEX_IS]`

Comment: `$myArray` does not contain `palle_tb` i'll add my new semi working attempt.

Comment: found out it didnt work when i had to insert second time, it would create a dublicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this instead.

```
  public function createGodTable()
{
    return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Angle`(
        id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(50),
        Datum VARCHAR(50), 
        Property VARCHAR(50), 
        Criterion VARCHAR(50), 
        Type VARCHAR(50), 
        Nominal DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Actual DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Tolminus DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Tolplus DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Dev DECIMAL(10,2), 
        Palle_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Varenummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Ordre_nummer VARCHAR(50), 
        Operatoer VARCHAR(50), 
        Maskine_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Raavare_batch_nr VARCHAR(50), 
        Dato_ur_stillet VARCHAR(50), 
        Klokke_fuldsvejst VARCHAR(50), 
        Fuldstoebning_af_klokke VARCHAR(50),
        Afgratning_af_overflade VARCHAR(50), 
        Vaegt DECIMAL(10,2))
      ");
}
public function insertGodTable($myArray)
{
    return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `Angle` (`Name`,`Datum`, `Property`, `Criterion`, `Type`, `Nominal`,
     `Actual`, `Tolminus`,`Tolplus`,`Dev`,`Palle_nr`,`Varenummer`,`Ordre_nummer`,`Operatoer`,`Maskine_nr`,`Raavare_batch_nr`,`Dato_ur_stillet`,`Klokke_fuldsvejst`,`fuldstoebning_af_klokke`,`Afgratning_af_overflade`,`Vaegt`)
    VALUES (:Name, :Datum, :Property, :Criterion, :Type, :Nominal, :Actual, :Tolminus,
     :Tolplus, :Dev, :Palle_nr, :Varenummer, :Ordre_nummer, :Operatoer, :Maskine_nr ,:Raavare_batch_nr, :Dato_ur_stillet, :Klokke_fuldsvejst, :Fuldstoebning_af_klokke, :Afgratning_af_overflade, :Vaegt)",
        [   
            ':Name' => $myArray[0],
            ':Datum' => $myArray[1],
            ':Property'=> $myArray[2],
            ':Criterion'=> $myArray[3],
            ':Type'=> $myArray[4],
            ':Nominal'=> $myArray[5],
            ':Actual'=> $myArray[6],
            ':Tolminus'=> $myArray[7],
            ':Tolplus'=> $myArray[8],
            ':Dev'=> $myArray[9],
            ':Palle_nr'=> $myArray[10],
            ':Varenummer'=> $myArray[11],
            ':Ordre_nummer' => $myArray[12],
            ':Operatoer'=> $myArray[13],
            ':Maskine_nr'=> $myArray[14],
            ':Raavare_batch_nr'=> $myArray[15],
            ':Dato_ur_stillet'=> $myArray[16],
            ':Klokke_fuldsvejst'=> $myArray[17],
            ':Fuldstoebning_af_klokke'=> $myArray[18],
            ':Afgratning_af_overflade'=> $myArray[19],
            ':Vaegt'=> $myArray[20]
        ]
    );
}
```